# Karma - base path not working properly

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

This is my first attempt of using karma, and I have some issues when trying to launch the tests.

My folder structure is the following:

```
node_modules
 -angular-mocks
src
 -compiled
 -lib
 -tests
   -karma.conf.js
```

Now, inside my karma.conf.js, this is my file list and basepath:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        basePath: '../../',

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        files: [
            {pattern: 'lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js', included: true, nocache: true, watched: true},
            {pattern: 'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', included: true, nocache: true, watched: true},
            'compiled/js/*.js',
            'compiled/css/*.css',
            {pattern: 'tests/unit/unit.js', included: true, nocache: true, watched: true}
    ],

    exclude: [],
```

I open the command prompt on another window and run karma using karma start, and all the browsers are opened and they are connected, not if I type karma run (while karma start is still running), the result is the following:

```
18 02 2016 08:35:26.708:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "c:/src/app/src/tests/src/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js" does not match any file.
18 02 2016 08:35:26.708:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "c:/src/app/src/tests/src/angular-mocks/angula-mocks.js" does not match any file.
18 02 2016 08:35:26.708:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "c:/src/app/src/tests/src/compiled/js/*.js" does not match any file.
18 02 2016 08:35:26.708:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "c:/src/app/src/tests/src/compiled/css/*.css" does not match any file.
18 02 2016 08:35:26.708:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "c:/src/app/src/tests/src/tests/unit/unit.js" does not match any file.
```

I can see that the file path is wrong, but I don't understand why...any help?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers: use `basePath: process.cwd()`.